# Run 2 node js socket.io projects in a single url

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a Nodejs server on amazon lightsail. I connected to it and made the necessary Apache configurations for Nodejs.

I have 2 Nodejs socket.io projects and I want to use both of them from a single URL.

These are the links in Nextjs

```
const [socket1, setSocket1] = useState<Socket | null>(null);
  const [socket2, setSocket2] = useState<Socket | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // first WebSocket
    const socketOne = io("https://....../", { path: "/ws", transports: ["websocket"] });
    setSocket1(socketOne);

    // second WebSocket
    const socketTwo = io("https://....../", { transports: ["websocket"] });
    setSocket2(socketTwo);

    // ComponentWillUnmount
    return () => {
      socketOne.disconnect();
      socketTwo.disconnect();
    };
  }, []); // only run once


 useEffect(() => {
    if (socket1) {
      socket1.on("connection", () => console.log("connected socket1"));
    }
  }, [socket1]);


  useEffect(() => {
    if (socket2) {
      socket2.on("connection", (data: any) => {
        console.log("Socket 2:", data);
      });
    }
  }, [socket2]);
```

server1 app

```
const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer, {transports: ["polling", "websocket",] , cors: {   origin: ["https://clienturl.com/"] } });
```

server1 app

```
const app = express();
const httpServer = createServer(app);
const io = new Server(httpServer, {transports: ["polling", "websocket",] , cors: {   origin: ["https://clienturl.com/"] } });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use namespaces for that. Basically you will start socket.io server on same url but different routes(socket.io calls it namespace). Here you can read more: https://socket.io/docs/v4/namespaces/
And this particular video also showcases namespace implementation in action:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZKEqqIO7n-k.